# Use Bootstrap 4 Modal confirmation dialog in form onsubmit function

Tags: jquery, flask, bootstrap-4

I have a form whose `onsubmit` validation works correctly using the html confirm() method. I want to replace the confirm method with a Bootstrap confirmation modal dialog, but have not found a way to keep the form from submitting until the user responds to the Bootstrap modal dialog. My current code is based this example: https://codepen.io/ajchambeaud/pen/KpVvMV

How do I keep the form from submitting long enough for the user to respond to the Bootstrap Modal dialog?

Here is an excerpt from the flask template that defines the form:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block main %}
  <div><br></div>
  <div class="card bg-light">
    <div class="card-body">

      <form name="fabricSpec" onsubmit="return validate();" method="post">

        <p>Select the number of shafts on your loom:
          <select name="shaftCount">
            <option value="8">&nbsp;&nbsp;8</option>
            {% for i in range(12, 100, 4) %}
              {% if i ==  shaft_count %}
                <option value="{{ i }}" selected>&nbsp;{{ i }}</option>
              {% else %}
                <option value="{{ i }}">&nbsp;{{ i }}</option>
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% for i in range(100, 201, 4) %}
              {% if i ==  shaft_count %}
                <option value="{{ i }}" selected>{{ i }}</option>
              {% else %}
                <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          </select>
        </p>

        <p>Select the number of blocks in your design:
          <select name="blockCount">
            {% for i in range(2, 10) %}
              {% if i ==  block_count %}
                <option value="{{ i }}" selected>&nbsp;{{ i }}</option>
              {% else %}
                <option value="{{ i }}">&nbsp;{{ i }}</option>
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% for i in range(10, 51) %}
              {% if i ==  block_count %}
                <option value="{{ i }}" selected>{{ i }}</option>
              {% else %}
                <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          </select>
        </p>

        <div class="col-6">
          <input class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" id="select_gif_btn"
                 formaction="{{ url_for('selectgif.select_gif_file') }}"
                 value="Read Weaves from GIF">

          <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="select_weaves_btn"
                 formaction="{{ url_for('weavemap.weave_map') }}"
                 value="Select Weaves">
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="warnModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="warnModalLabel"
       aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="warnModalLabel">Warning</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button id="modal-btn-yes" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Yes</button>
          <button id="modal-btn-no" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">No</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
  <script language="javascript">

    // based on https://codepen.io/ajchambeaud/pen/KpVvMV
    var modalConfirm = function (callback) {
      $("#modal-btn-yes").on("click", function (e) {
        callback(true);
        $("#warnModal").modal('hide');
      });

      $("#modal-btn-no").on("click", function (e) {
        callback(false);
        $("#warnModal").modal('hide');
      });
    }

    function showWarnModal(message) {
      $('#warnModal .modal-body').text(message);
      $('#warnModal').modal('show');

      modalConfirm(function (confirm) {
        if (confirm) {
          console.log('confirmed');
          window.document.fabricSpec.submit();
        } else {
          console.log('not confirmed');
        }
      });
    }

    function validate() {
      var form = window.document.fabricSpec;
      var shaftCount = form.shaftCount.value;
      var blockCount = form.blockCount.value;
      var valid = true;
      if (blockCount * 4 > shaftCount) {
        var warning = "You specified more blocks than your loom can weave without using pickup. " +
          "Do you wish to Proceed?"
        valid = confirm(warning);
        {#showWarnModal(warning);#}
        {#valid = false;#}
      }
      console.log('valid:', valid);
      return valid;
    }

  </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set the form's action in the confirmation modal dialog's callback.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block main %}
  <div><br></div>
  <div class="card bg-light">
    <div class="card-body">

      <form name="fabricSpec" method="post">

        <p>Select the number of shafts on your loom:
          <select name="shaftCount">
            <option value="8">&nbsp;&nbsp;8</option>
            {% for i in range(12, 100, 4) %}
              {% if i ==  shaft_count %}
                <option value="{{ i }}" selected>&nbsp;{{ i }}</option>
              {% else %}
                <option value="{{ i }}">&nbsp;{{ i }}</option>
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% for i in range(100, 201, 4) %}
              {% if i ==  shaft_count %}
                <option value="{{ i }}" selected>{{ i }}</option>
              {% else %}
                <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          </select>
        </p>

        <p>Select the number of blocks in your design:
          <select name="blockCount">
            {% for i in range(2, 10) %}
              {% if i ==  block_count %}
                <option value="{{ i }}" selected>&nbsp;{{ i }}</option>
              {% else %}
                <option value="{{ i }}">&nbsp;{{ i }}</option>
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% for i in range(10, 51) %}
              {% if i ==  block_count %}
                <option value="{{ i }}" selected>{{ i }}</option>
              {% else %}
                <option value="{{ i }}">{{ i }}</option>
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          </select>
        </p>

        <div class="col-6">
          <input class="btn btn-secondary"
                 type="button"
                 name="read_weaves_btn"
                 onclick="readWeavesValidateAndSubmit()"
                 value="Read Weaves from GIF">

          <input class="btn btn-primary"
                 type="button"
                 name="select_weaves_btn"
                 onclick="selectWeavesValidateAndSubmit()"
                 value="Select Weaves">
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="warnModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="warnModalLabel"
       aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="warnModalLabel">Warning</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button id="modal-btn-yes" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Yes</button>
          <button id="modal-btn-no" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">No</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

{% endblock %}


{% block scripts %}
  <script language="javascript">

    // based on https://codepen.io/ajchambeaud/pen/KpVvMV
    var modalConfirm = function (callback) {
      $("#modal-btn-yes").on("click", function (e) {
        callback(true);
        $("#warnModal").modal('hide');
      });

      $("#modal-btn-no").on("click", function (e) {
        callback(false);
        $("#warnModal").modal('hide');
      });
    }

    function showWarnModal(message, formaction) {
      $('#warnModal .modal-body').text(message);
      $('#warnModal').modal('show');

      modalConfirm(function (confirm) {
        if (confirm) {
          console.log('confirmed');
          var form = window.document.fabricSpec;
          form.action = formaction;
          form.submit()
        } else {
          console.log('not confirmed');
        }
      });
    }

    function validate(formaction) {
      var form = window.document.fabricSpec;
      var shaftCount = form.shaftCount.value;
      var blockCount = form.blockCount.value;
      var valid = true;
      if (blockCount * 4 > shaftCount) {
        var warning = "You specified more blocks than your loom can weave without using pickup. " +
          "Do you wish to Proceed?"
        {#valid = confirm(warning);#}
        showWarnModal(warning, formaction);
        valid = false;
      }
      console.log('validate: valid:', valid);
      return valid;
    }

    function readWeavesValidateAndSubmit() {
      var formaction = "{{ url_for('selectgif.select_gif_file', _external=True) }}";
      console.log("formaction: ", formaction)
      if (validate(formaction)) {
        var form = window.document.fabricSpec;
        form.action = formaction;
        form.submit()
      }
    }

    function selectWeavesValidateAndSubmit() {
      var formaction = "{{ url_for('weavemap.weave_map', _external=True) }}";
      console.log("formaction: ", formaction)
      if (validate(formaction)) {
        var form = window.document.fabricSpec;
        form.action = formaction;
        form.submit()
      }
    }

  </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set an id on your form tag and then submit your form with jquery when the user clicked on the confirm button. So you should change your modalConfirm function to this:

```js
modalConfirm(function(confirm){
    if(confirm){
        //Acciones si el usuario confirma
        $("#result").html("CONFIRMADO");
        $('#form-id').trigger('submit');   //Add this line and set your form id
    }else{
        //Acciones si el usuario no confirma
        $("#result").html("NO CONFIRMADO");
    }
});
```

Comment: The form submittal in the original excerpt failed due to the form not defining an action.